# Google sheets exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' - error 429

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread, http-status-code-429

i'm having the following error :

> gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 429, 'message': "Quota exceeded
> for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute
> per user' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer
> 'project_number:981210703596'.", 'status': 'RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED',
> 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo',
> 'reason': 'RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com',
> 'metadata': {'quota_limit_value': '300', 'consumer':
> 'projects/981210703596', 'quota_location': 'global', 'service':
> 'sheets.googleapis.com', 'quota_limit':
> 'ReadRequestsPerMinutePerUser', 'quota_metric':
> 'sheets.googleapis.com/read_requests'}}, {'@type':
> 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links': [{'description':
> 'Request a higher quota limit.', 'url':
> 'https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota'}]}]}

And this is my code:

```
def agregar_datos_a_sheet(self, poblacion, sustitutos, modulos, fecha_inicio, fecha_final, worksheet, ambiente):
    # Creamos una lista con los datos a agregar
    modulos = modulos.split(",")
    datos_usuarios = []
    for i in range(len(poblacion)):
        datos_usuarios.append(
            [poblacion[i], '', sustitutos[i], '', fecha_inicio, fecha_final])
    if ambiente == 'MercadoP':
        permisos = Configuration_Manager().get_proxy_ssff()['Permisos_Mercado_P']
    else:
        permisos = Configuration_Manager().get_proxy_ssff()['Permisos_Mercado_D']
    #Inserto los IDs de usuarios y fechas
    worksheet.sheet1.insert_rows(datos_usuarios, row=2)
    time.sleep(60)
    for modulo in modulos:
        if modulo in permisos:
            columnas_permisos = permisos[modulo]
            num_usuarios = int(len(poblacion))
            update_requests = []
            #try:
            for i in range(2, num_usuarios + 2):
                for col in columnas_permisos:
                    update_requests.append({
                        'updateCells': {
                            'rows': {
                                'values': [{
                                    'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': 'YES'}
                                }]
                            },
                            'fields': 'userEnteredValue',
                            'start': {
                                'sheetId': worksheet.sheet1.id,
                                'rowIndex': i - 1,
                                'columnIndex': col - 1
                            }
                        }
                    })
            batch_update_requests = {'requests': update_requests}
            worksheet.batch_update(batch_update_requests)
            time.sleep(60)
```

The main problem is that i'm debugging this code and it fails before getting to line
`worksheet.batch_update(batch_update_requests)`
which is where I would expect for the error to rise.

The data im using is this:

```
Modulos:  ['cm', 'pm']
poblacion : ['30038393', '30034917', '30019948', '30041170', '30024223', '30038393', '30034917', '30019948', '30041170', '30024223', '30038393', '30034917', '30019948', '30041170', '30024223', '30038393', '30034917', '30019948', '30041170', '30024223', '30038393', '30034917', '30019948', '30041170', '30024223']

sustitutos: ['30038393', '30038393', '30038393', '30038393', '30038393', '30034917', '30034917', '30034917', '30034917', '30034917', '30019948', '30019948', '30019948', '30019948', '30019948', '30041170', '30041170', '30041170', '30041170', '30041170', '30024223', '30024223', '30024223', '30024223', '30024223']

fecha_inicio : '01-03-2023 00:00'

fecha_final : '11-03-2023 00:00'

permisos : {'rc': [11, 15, 18, 21, 29, 33, 36], 'ec': [11, 21, 22, 33, 36],
           'pm': [9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 23, 24, 26, 28, 32, 38, 39, 40], 'cm': [10, 14, 16,        20, 22, 33, 36]}
```

I've tried everything and I cannot find the reason why i'm getting 429 code error.
Thanks for any help you can provide!

Added time.sleep , changed append.rows() for insert_row() but error still persists

Comment: you should look on https://console.cloud.google.com/ to see what your quota is, because the response is saying that you have gone over your quota. If you haven't gone over your quota please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this!
The issue was that i was using

```
'sheetId': worksheet.sheet1.id'
```

on the JSON, which I guess consumed an API Call every time I iterated over the JSON to add an user.
I added

```
worksheet_id = worksheet.sheet1.id
```

and then replaced

```
'sheetId': worksheet_id,
```